# Creating graph with timeline in javascript

Tags: javascript, graph, visualization, timeline, gojs

I would like to create dynamically changing graph with timeline in javascript, That would look something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8ABU.jpg).
Edit: I would like to decide by myself which node should be in which time slice.

I wonder, is there a library that I can use to do this, or I need to create it by myself ( by simply drawing on canvas )? I tried to find one, however it seems that there are many implementations of timelines and of graphs but the combination of those two is hard to find. The most suitable solution was using [gojs](http://gojs.net/latest/samples/swimBands.html). However I can't create a node with two parents in it because it is implemented as a tree data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As that [GoJS sample](http://gojs.net/latest/samples/swimBands.html) mentions in the text, it is easy to replace the **TreeLayout** with a **LayeredDigraphLayout** and the **TreeModel** with a **GraphLinksModel**. Here's what I just did to modify the sample.

Replace `go.TreeLayout` with `go.LayeredDigraphLayout`, so that the custom layout no longer inherits from TreeLayout.  Change the constructor not to bother setting TreeLayout specific properties.  Change the diagram's layout to use LayeredDigraphLayout specific properties:

```
            layout: $(LayeredTreeLayout,  // custom layout is defined above
                      {
                        angle: HORIZONTAL ? 0 : 90,
                        columnSpacing: 5,
                        layeringOption: go.LayeredDigraphLayout.LayerLongestPathSource
                      }),
```

Replace that sample's model with a GraphLinksModel holding the data that you want:

```
// define the node data
var nodearray = [
  { // this is the information needed for the headers of the bands
    key: "_BANDS",
    category: "Bands",
    itemArray: [
      { text: "Day 0" },
      { text: "Day 1" },
      { text: "Day 2" },
      { text: "Day 3" },
      { text: "Day 4" },
      { text: "Day 5" }
    ]
  }
];
var linkarray = [
  { from: "A", to: "D" },
  { from: "B", to: "D" },
  { from: "D", to: "E" },
  { from: "D", to: "F" },
  { from: "C", to: "F" }
];

myDiagram.model = $(go.GraphLinksModel,
    { // automatically create node data objects for each "from" or "to" reference
      // (set this property before setting the linkDataArray)
      archetypeNodeData: {},
      nodeDataArray: nodearray,
      linkDataArray: linkarray
    });
```

Without having changed any of the templates or the styling, the result is:

[image]

Just to make sure it works, I also tried setting `HORIZONTAL = false`:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that really helped me. However, I have a problem, I would like  [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKSBY.jpg) to work as well. Specifically, that would be great if I could decide by myself which node should be in which time slice.

Answer (score 2):

You may have to play around with the maths, but I hope this will be useful as a starting point:

**DEMO**: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rrcm1dg4/)

**HTML**

```
<div id='board'>
 <div id='titles'></div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#board { 
  position: relative; 
  width: 500px;
  height: 600px;
  background-color:#f83213;
}
#titles {
  color: #ffffff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 18px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
#titles div {
  display:inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
}
.event{
    border: 0px;
    background-color: #3a2356;
    color: #ffffff;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 4px;
    font-size: 18px;
    z-index: 2;
}
.line{
    height: 1px;
    width: 60px;
    background-color: #3a2356;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

** JavaScript**

```
var margin = 20;
var events = {
  "A": {
    day: 0,
    indexInDay: 0,
    lineTos: ["D"]
  },
  "B": {
    day: 0,
    indexInDay: 1,
    lineTos: ["D"]
  },
  "D": {
    day: 1,
    indexInDay: 0,
    lineTos: ["E","F"]
  },
  "E": {
    day: 2,
    indexInDay: 0,
    lineTos: null
  },
  "C": {
    day: 0,
    indexInDay: 2,
    lineTos: ["F"]
  },
  "F": {
    day: 2,
    indexInDay: 2,
    lineTos: null
  },
};

drawAll(events);

function drawAll(events) {
  drawTitles(events);
  drawEvents(events);
  drawLines(events);
}

function drawTitles(events) {
  var titles = document.getElementById('titles');
  var max = 0;
  for (var name in events) {
    if (events[name].day > max)
      max = events[name].day;
  }
  for (var i = 0 ; i <= max ; i++)
    titles.innerHTML += '<div>' + 'Day' + i + '</div>';
}

function drawEvents(events) {
  var board = document.getElementById('board');
  for (var name in events) {
    var ev = events[name];
    var eventDiv = document.createElement('DIV');
    board.appendChild(eventDiv);
    eventDiv.className = 'event';
    setTopLeftEvent(ev, eventDiv);
    eventDiv.innerText = name;

  }
}

function drawLines(events) {
  var board = document.getElementById('board');
  for (var name in events) {
    var from = events[name];
    var tos = from.lineTos;
    if (!tos) continue;
    for (var j = 0 ; j < tos.length ; j++) {
      var to = events[tos[j]];
      var lineDiv = document.createElement('DIV');
      board.appendChild(lineDiv);
      lineDiv.className = 'line';
      setTopLeftLine(from, lineDiv);
      lineDiv.style.width = margin  + 1 * margin * distance(to.indexInDay,from.indexInDay,to.day, from.day) + 'px';
      var tan = (to.indexInDay - from.indexInDay) / (to.day - from.day);
      lineDiv.style.top = lineDiv.offsetTop + (tan * margin) +'px';
      var angle = Math.atan(tan) * 180/Math.PI;
      // Code for Safari
      lineDiv.style.WebkitTransform = "rotate(" + angle + "deg)"; 
      // Code for IE9
      lineDiv.style.msTransform = "rotate(" + angle + "deg)"; 
      // Standard syntax
      lineDiv.style.transform = "rotate(" + angle + "deg)"; 
    }

  }
}

function distance(x1, y1, x2, y2){
 var res = Math.sqrt((y2-y1)*(y2-y1) + (x2-x1)*(x2-x1)); 
 return res;
}

function setTopLeftEvent(event, eventDiv) {
  eventDiv.style.left = (margin + event.day * (margin * 2)) + 'px';
    eventDiv.style.top = (margin * 2 + event.indexInDay * (margin * 2)) + 'px';
}
function setTopLeftLine(event, lineDiv) {
  lineDiv.style.left = (margin + event.day * (margin * 2)) + 'px';
  lineDiv.style.top = (margin * 2.5 + event.indexInDay * (margin * 2)) + 'px';
}
```